# Java Google Analytics API / Returning null pointer exception when tries to get results

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

For some reason is returning null when tries to get results, somebody has seen this?

When debuging, he goes to the exception on main method, right when he reads this line :

```
printResults(getResults(analytics, profile));
```

He does reach the profile ID, although its not working on the method results, my google analytics account is working just fine

I get this in console:

First Profile Id: 166128559

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at HelloAnalytics.printResults(HelloAnalytics.java:99)
    at HelloAnalytics.main(HelloAnalytics.java:33)
```

**Code :**

```
public class HelloAnalytics {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Hello Analytics";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "C:/Users/Shell/workspace/relatorio-analytics/src/main/java/client_secrets.p12";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "shell-121@projeto-analytics-188712.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();

        String profile = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
        System.out.println("First Profile Id: " + profile);
        printResults(getResults(analytics, profile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.

    // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
    // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all()).build();

    // Construct the Analytics service object.
    return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}

private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
    // Get the first view (profile) ID for the authorized user.
    String profileId = null;

    // Query for the list of all accounts associated with the service account.
    Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

    if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No accounts found");
    } else {
        String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();

        // Query for the list of properties associated with the first account.
        Webproperties properties = analytics.management().webproperties().list(firstAccountId).execute();

        if (properties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
        } else {
            String firstWebpropertyId = properties.getItems().get(0).getId();

            // Query for the list views (profiles) associated with the property.
            Profiles profiles = analytics.management().profiles().list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId)
                    .execute();

            if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println("No views (profiles) found");
            } else {
                // Return the first (view) profile associated with the property.
                profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
            }
        }
    }
    return profileId;
}

private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    // Query the Core Reporting API for the number of sessions
    // in the past seven days.
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions").execute();
}

private static void printResults(GaData results) {
    // Parse the response from the Core Reporting API for
    // the profile name and number of sessions.
    if (results != null && !results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("View (Profile) Name: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + results.getRows().get(0).get(0));
    } else {
        System.out.println("No results found");
    }
}
```

Comment: `results.getRows()` returns `null` and throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Do you have any idea what should I do? Sorry my knowledge is very limited still

Comment: Add another null-check, `if (results != null && results.getRows() != null && !results.getRows().isEmpty()) {`. Also don't access a list with `.get(0)` when you don't know how long it is.